# How would I go about creating a product in the Stripe extension in Firebase using flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments, firebase-extensions

I am building an event management app and am currently in the stage of adding payment funcionality to it. I have followed the firebase documentation and all seems to be in working order and I can easily add products to my firestore database when using the Stripe dashboard. I am just wondering how this could be done either client side (flutter) or using cloud functions?

I have tried watching tutorials, looking at the limited github examples and reading the documentation however all the products seem to be made through the stripe dashboard - obviously not ideal to have to manually create every one!

Answer (score 1):

Creating Products via the Stripe API requires an Account's secret API key.  You should **never** expose this since it provides full access to your account.  So creating Products from the client-side is not something we will consider.

Additionally the [Stripe Firebase Extension](https://extensions.dev/extensions/stripe/firestore-stripe-payments) does not include any cloud functions for creating Products.  The docs even have you create a restricted key to keep your account safe.  All of that suggests to me that you will want to either

1. Create products from the [Stripe Dashboard](https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/manage-prices?dashboard-or-api=dashboard) as previously indicated in tutorials and documentation.
2. Run local scripts to [create products](https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/manage-prices?dashboard-or-api=api) via the API using one of Stripe's client libraries which you can install locally.